# Sending email in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to send an email without opening an email client and without using any external libraries such as JavaMail API in Android?

Answer (score 0):

No, Android does not provide any way to send an email without opening a client. Why don't you want to use JavaMail?

Another way to do it is to use `java.net.Socket` to connect directly to an SMTP server. Doing it yourself is a lot easier than it sounds because the protocol is quite simple and it's even human readable.

This page shows an example of the SMTP conversation for sending a plain text email:
http://www.smtp2go.com/articles/smtp-protocol.html

Barry